# Access Variable in a Data Frame List

Tags: r

Quick question:

How can I access a variable directly out of a dataframes list?

I tried

```
df_list[i]$variable which is not working.
or df_list[(i)]$variable...
or df_list[i[1]]
```

is there a way?

Comment: Do you need `df_list[[i]]$variable` ?

Comment: Oh wow only thing I haven't tried. Thank you!!

Comment: or `lapply(df_list, function(x) x$variable )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `[[` to access the dataframe inside the list. I am assuming you are running in a `for` loop. To access the `variable` you may use `df_list[[i]]$variable`.

You may also read [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)